# How to delete the first line suitable for the requirements? - MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, limit, sql-delete

I have such a code,

```sql
DELETE FROM queue WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM queue WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1)
```

but when starting, such an error appears

`This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Can you tell me how to do without a tag `IN` or to realize it at all differently? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `id` column Unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB and MySql allow an `ORDER BY` clause (which you should use) and `LIMIT` in a [`DELETE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/) statement:

```
DELETE FROM queue 
WHERE id = %s
-- ORDER BY ....
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with phrasing your logic as a delete join:

```sql
DELETE q1
FROM queue q1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM queue
    WHERE id = %s
    -- ORDER BY some column here
    LIMIT 1
) q2
    ON q2.id = q1.id;
```

But note that if you are using `LIMIT`, you should really also be using `ORDER BY`.  I have added a placeholder in the subquery for an `ORDER BY` clause.